# k8s nginx ingress TLS rules: cert vs. paths

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

I am struggling to get my nginx ingress (on AWS EKS) working with path rules and TLS.

The ingress is from
[here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml)

A snippet from the Ingress looks like:

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
    secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-service
            port:
              number: 443
```

This ingress creates the AWS network load balancer, with a URL like
`https://xyz.elb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/`

I am updating the
`ingress-tls`
secret with a certificate using
`cert-manager`.

When I access the ingress using the NLB URL
`https://xyz.elb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/api`, I get

1. GOOD: Correct routing based on the path rules from the ingress definition (i.e. it ​goes to my
   `api-service` as expected)
2. BAD: Certificate errors since I'm not accessing the ingress with the domain that the certificate is for.

When I access the ingress using the correct domain e.g.
`https://example.com/api` which is what I want to do, I get:

1. BAD:
   `404`, it doesn't respect my path rules, and goes to
   `upstream-default-backend` instead.
2. GOOD: certificate all good, it’s the one for
   `example.com` that
   `cert-manager` configured.

I tried removing the
`host: example.com` from the
`rules:`, which gives me:

1. GOOD: Correct routing based on the path rules from the ingress definition
2. BAD: Certificate errors, it serves up the default ingress “Fake” certificate instead of the one for
   `example.com`, I guess since the
   `host` is missing from the rules, though not sure of the exact reason.

Can someone please help me get

1. GOOD
2. GOOD

I’m at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

After staring at this for several more hours, and digging through the nasty chunk of lua that is the
`nginx.conf` for this, I found it!  Maybe someday someone will have this problem, and might find this useful.

The problem was:

```
  rules:
  - host: example.com
  - http:
```

This is defining (I think) a
`host` with no forwarding rules, then then some
`http` forwarding rules without a host.  What I had intended was obviously that the forwarding rules would be for the host.

And that would be:

```
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
```

I have to say that I'm now even less of a fan of YAML than I was previously, if that's even possible.